# DESede decryption in java a block encrypted in C# using key generated by CryptDeriveKey method

Tags: java, encryption, salt, tripledes

I have a data block, which can be decrypted in C# with this code:

```
    PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);       
    byte[] key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, iv);        
    var csp = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    csp.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    csp.IV = iv;
    csp.Key = key;
    csp.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

    var plainTextBytes = new byte[32*1024];
    var decryptor = csp.CreateDecryptor();
    int decr = decryptor.TransformBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length, plainTextBytes, 0);
```

My main goal to do the same in java. I'm trying to do this with this  [PasswordDerivedBytes port](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22271/what-is-the-algorithm-behind-passwordderivebytes) solution.

Here is my code:

```
PasswordDeriveBytes myPass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);
SecretKeyFactory kf;
    try {
        Cipher desEDE = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CB/NoPadding");
        kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        key = myPass.getBytes(192);
        desEDEKey= kf.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(key));           
        byte[] iv = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(ivText);
        desEDE.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desEDEKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] ct = desEDE.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(texts));   
    }
```

The problem is that the key created by C# CryptDerviedKey is not equal to one generated in java with getBytes(192). When this key is just copied from C# to java then all work fine, so the problem exactly in this place. Please help to port CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, iv) algorithm to java correctly;